# Best mobile games resolution ratio

Tags: java, libgdx

What is the best landscape and portrait resolution ratios that will fit the most of the devices out there and the black bars size will be minimum?

Comment: What have you researched?  The question appears to be too broad.

Comment: We'd also need to know more about the nature of what you are displaying. Can you pad with a background image? Can you increase the field of view to use any display shape? Why must your game must have a fixed aspect ratio? Check out the section titled "The Problems of Resolution and Aspect Ratio", starting at page 113 of [this online book](http://books.google.com/books?id=6SULAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA114&dq=mobile%20device%20aspect%20ratios%20game%20design&pg=PA114#v=onepage&q=mobile%20device%20aspect%20ratios%20game%20design&f=false) (link is to page 114, scroll up a bit) and continuing to page 116.

Answer (score 1):

For minimizing the amount of black bars you should aim around the median ratio of target devices, that would probably be 8:5 or 5:3.

But if you really need your game to be a fixed ratio, consider using some filler art instead of black bars, you might simply have a playing field background with some out of bounds area that is cropped away depending on screen aspect ratio.